# intellisense failing for with-statement in python3.8

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, intellisense, with-statement, python-3.8

I put together a simple block of code such as:

```
def withBlock():
    with open('foo.txt', 'w') as file:
        file.write('foo')

def nextFunction():
    print('bar')
```

in Visual Studio 2017, I get issues with intellisense with Python 3.8 activated. This issue is not present when Python 3.6 is active. It will indicate `with: <unknown type>` and `unexpected token 'open'`. After this statement the rest of the code has several intellisense errors. Running this code in the interpreter performs exactly as expected.

My specific issue comes with using

```
with self.assertRaises(ValueError):
    self.data.TestHeader = testHeader
```

in the middle of a series of tests. Once this test is reached, all following tests are ignored in the test explorer. Running the tests from the command line outside of Visual Studio works perfectly fine.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try deleting the hidden .vs folder in solution directory after closing vs instance, and restart VS. Or unload and reload the project may help?

Comment: @GardenCat neither attempt helped. It does look like if I start a fresh project and add the above code there is no issue with intellisense. If I delete the project in my current case and make a new one the issue persists. I will have to keep trying things...

Comment: Determined that this is a Python 3.8 specific issue, updated question with this new understanding.

Comment: @LuciusSilanus Agree with you:) I check the release date of python 3.8, and the default python component VS suggests, in VS2017, I suggest using python 3.6... :-)

Answer (score 0):

For now the latest release VS2019 is VS2019 `16.3.9` and the latest VS2017 is `15.9.17`.

[image]

[image]

Please check the default Python components VS ide supports, for now in VS2017 the Python `3.6` is supported instead of the `3.8` which released in October by [Python.org](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html). So i assume that there's possibility that Python 3.8 feature are not fully supported in VS2017 now. And it could be the cause of your original issue. Hope it helps to resolve your puzzle :)